# Drupal 7 - How to hide and show options of a drop down in a form

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom form in drupal 7 and I want to hide and show options of a dropdown by different conditions. Is there any way to do this? I have tried with `unset($form['dropdown'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options'][5])` but unable to show it in the next condition. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic drop down using #ajax call as per your conditions. If your drop down is dependent on some other field you can use drupal ajax_form_dependent_dropdown and can create dynamic select list options. For reference you can checkout the following links.

[AJAX-based dropdown example form](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example.module/function/ajax_example_dependent_dropdown/7)

[Dynamic select list in the form (dependent dropdown)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10112/dynamic-select-list-in-the-form-dependent-dropdown)